# Spring MVC view/controller test of known good tiles setup fails with assertion error

Tags: java, spring, tiles2, spring-test

I have this MVC Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {
    if (page != null || size != null) {
        int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
        final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("smaker", Smak.findSmakEntries(firstResult, sizeNo, sortFieldName, sortOrder));
        float nrOfPages = (float) Smak.countSmaker() / sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("maxPages", (int) ((nrOfPages > (int) nrOfPages || nrOfPages == 0.0) ? nrOfPages + 1 : nrOfPages));
    } else {
        uiModel.addAttribute("smaker", Smak.findAllSmaker(sortFieldName, sortOrder));
    }
    return "smaker/list";
}
```

}

I use Tiles 2.2.2 and I have this view renders when the web app runs in Jetty, but I wanted to evaluate spring-test so I started with this simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ViewsControllerTests extends AbstractContextControllerTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).alwaysExpect(status().isOk()).build();
    }//wac is in the superclass which loads it from file

    @Test
    public void getSmakerView() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/smaker"))
                .andExpect(view().name(containsString("smaker/list")));
    }

}
```

Indeed I have `Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView` name 'smaker/list'; in the logs when I run this project in Jetty.

Yet when I run tests the test above it fails with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: a string containing "smaker/list but: was "uncaughtException"
```

which is my default ErrorView for my SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.
**So something would seem to be wrong with either my test or my assumptions on what it does. Any ideas what my mistake could be here?**

Comment: Do you use a different context (web or application) for test than for running your application? Seems to me like something in your controller method might cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use the same webmvc context when running the web app as when run the tests, but in the test I don't load the application context, of course. Nothing related in there though. 

Given that the controller works when run in Jetty, why do you think the issue would lie there? My conclusion is the opposite that as the controller works when run in Jetty, it can be regarded as known working. I think it's in the setup. But where? That's the question.

Comment: Anyway, I added the body of the relevant controller method. Does this seem problematic in the context of testing it?

Comment: Maybe the uncaught exception is a result of the `Smak.findAllSmaker(sortFieldName, sortOrder));` call? Did you mock this repository or something else? That's why I asked for the spring context.

Comment: Good call. I seem to have forgotten about mocks for whatever stupid reason. I'll look over this to make sure and will report report back. Big thank you for this observation I should have realized myself. I'll suggest you write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the call of

```
uiModel.addAttribute("smaker", Smak.findAllSmaker(sortFieldName, sortOrder));
```

especially this part: `Smak.findAllSmaker`
Without any application context and resulting dependency injection or mocking this line will produce the problem you are facing.